# Working Time Regulations UK

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts, work-time

My new contract is stating that the maximum weekly working time in the Working Time Regulations will not apply to me.

I know that you can opt out of this regulation, but should I be concerned that it is in there to begin with? My normal hours of work is 40 hrs per week.

Comment: Talk to the citizen's advice (they are trained to advise you correctly on matters like this for free), this kind of advice is off topic here, and not the kind of thing you want random strangers on the internet to tell you. Voting to close.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager This is not off-topic at all. Legal information of the sort that an HR specialist or other individual with familiarity of the type of situation is well-versed is fine. This is not "advice". It's legal information which is acceptable. Nothing here is specific or requires a lawyer. http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694/28939

Comment: @ChristopherEstep - when the choice is a call for free and accurate advice from the citz or a random stranger on the Internet who may (or may not)  know the right answer I say talk to those who know and "advice"  from here is worth what you pay for it, so while not legal advice,  still something to ask a qualified person,  so off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My new contract is stating that the maximum weekly working time in the Working Time Regulations will not apply to me.

This may simply be a true statement, rather than an attempt to opt you out of the directive in the contract (in that it is a job excluded from the rule by the Working Time Directive, e.g. armed forces). There is [general information on this from gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/maximum-weekly-working-hours/overview). There are also occupations where you cannot opt out and your time is subject to other regulations, often for the safety of others (e.g. [heavy goods vehicle drivers](https://www.gov.uk/maximum-weekly-working-hours/weekly-maximum-working-hours-and-opting-out)).

If you are being offered a new contract and being asked to opt out at the same time, you are more likely to be in a strong place bargaining-wise. Remember, you can refuse now and keep your current job: once you accept, there are restrictions on when you can do so (the TUC's Worksmart service has [good advice on this (pdf)](https://www.tuc.org.uk/sites/default/files/tuc/optout.pdf)).

If you otherwise have no problem with the job offer, you could return the contract with the relevant part struck through: that would force them to either accept the change or tell you it's mandatory (in which case you have either their reason, or else you can keep working your existing contract). It may be a sign they have a long-hours culture, but might just that they want to avoid responsibility. If it's an office job, 40 hours is long to begin with for the UK, 35-38 is more typical. If you know and trust someone who already works there (not the hiring manager or HR contact), you could ask them to see if long hours are ever an issue.

If they want to keep the clause and the job offer is still tempting, asking about their overtime arrangements may help you decide - e.g. would you work 48h+ if they paid 'double time' for the additional hours?